# Synthesizing SV interface dereferencing ports

Tags: interface, system, verilog, synthesis

I'd like to synthesize the following using an interface defined as following

```
interface smb_if #(
  parameter shortint ADDR_SZ   = 8,
  parameter shortint DATA_SZ   = 8,
  parameter shortint SLAVE_NUM = 8
);
  logic [DATA_SZ-1:0]   wrdata;
  logic [DATA_SZ-1:0]   rddata [SLAVE_NUM-1:0];
  logic [ADDR_SZ-1:0]   rdaddr;
  logic [ADDR_SZ-1:0]   wraddr;
  logic                 wr;                  // =1 means 'write, =0 means 'read
  logic                 wrcmd;               //
  logic                 rd;                  // =1 means 'write, =0 means 'read
  logic                 rdcmd;                // =1 means 'write, =0 means 'read
  logic [ADDR_SZ-1:0]   rdaddr_old;
  logic                 clrcmd;
  logic [SLAVE_NUM-1:0] sel ; // one-hot; =1 means 'selected'
  modport master (
    input  rddata, output wrdata, output rdaddr, output rdaddr_old, output clrcmd, output wraddr,
    output wr, output wrcmd, output rd, output rdcmd, output sel
  );
  modport slave  (
    output rddata, input  wrdata, input  rdaddr, input rdaddr_old, input clrcmd, input  wraddr,
    input  wr, input wrcmd, input rd,  input rdcmd, input  sel
  );

endinterface:smb_if
```

An instance of the interface is declare in my top module as following

```
smb_if #(.ADDR_SZ(8), .SLAVE_NUM(8)) i_smbif();
```

I then connect the interface port to my module

```
.smb_page_sel        (i_smbif.master.sel                ),   // Page selection
.smb_addw            (i_smbif.master.wraddr             ),   // data address for write
.smb_dataw           (i_smbif.master.wrdata             ),   // data to be written on a write cycle
.smb_wr              (i_smbif.master.wr                 ),   // from SMB top: what diff with wr?
.smb_wrcmd           (i_smbif.master.wrcmd              ),   // register file write command
.smb_addptr          (i_smbif.master.rdaddr             ),   // data address for read
.smb_rd              (i_smbif.master.rd),
// etc.
```

I got an error from design compiler during elaboration (analyse did run fine)

Can anybody suggest a workaround? I do not want to modify the port map of the DUT which is a legacy verilog 2001 code

Simulation with NCVLOG works fine, though
thanks much

Answer (score 0):

The modport information should not be specified in the connection.
The modport you use should be declared in the port declaration of the module using the interface.

If you declare your interface in the module where you want to use it then you do not have to specify each port.

I think that you will have to modify the code to make it comply with DC. But it is for the best as using interfaces makes your code shorter and clearer.

FYI, a quick example of interface utilization :

Interface declaration

```
interface channel(
  logic request;
  logic acknowledge;
  modport src ( output request, input  acknowledge);
  modport dst ( input  request, output acknowledge);
endinterface
```

Source module decl

```
module source(
  Channel.src myChannel_out
);
  //Do stuff
endmodule
```

Dest module decl

```
module destination(
  Channel.dst myChannel_in
);
  //Do stuff
endmodule
```

Top module

```
module top ();

  Channel myChannel ();
  source u_source(
  .myChannel_out(myChannel)
  );
  destination u_destination(
   .myChannel_in(myChannel)
  );
endmodule
```

I am using this with Design Compiler without any issue so far.